# Delete rows of Data Frames inside a List by condition in R

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames like this:

```
$data_type1
   Species_Name X.micron. Y.micron. Type
1     Cerulean+    903.59    715.00    1
2     Cerulean+   1136.70    795.88    1
3     Cerulean+    559.53    759.29    1
4     Cerulean+    921.69     35.87    1

$data_type2
   Species_Name X.micron. Y.micron. Type
1       Cherry+   490.070    360.15    2
2       Cherry+   766.810    696.30    2
3       Cherry+   797.730    787.09    2
4       Cherry+   842.870   1096.40    2

$data_type3
    Species_Name X.micron. Y.micron. Type
1           GFP+     60.85    45.170    3
2           GFP+    187.03   699.990    3
3           GFP+    405.63   864.510    3
4           GFP+    995.68  1153.000    3

$data_type5
      Species_Name X.micron. Y.micron. Type
1 Cerulean+Cherry+    270.37    944.59    5
2 Cerulean+Cherry+    377.66    845.79    5

$data_type6
    Species_Name X.micron. Y.micron. Type
1  Cerulean+GFP+   1013.80    716.84    6
2  Cerulean+GFP+   1035.10    140.22    6
3  Cerulean+GFP+   1038.50    133.05    6
4  Cerulean+GFP+   1066.30   1001.60    6

$data_type8
          Species_Name X.micron. Y.micron. Type
1 Cerulean+Cherry+GFP+    270.37    944.59    8
2 Cerulean+Cherry+GFP+    377.66    845.79    8
```

I would like to remove duplicated rows based on `X.micron.` `Y.micron.` and `Species_Name` columns but with a special condition:

Just delete the rows of the data frames with names already included in another data frame and from more names to less, i.e. `X.micron.` and `Y.micron.` matching values between `$data_type8` with `Species_Name = Cerulean+Cherry+GFP+` and `$data_type5` with `Species_Name = Cerulean+Cherry+` can only be in `$data_type8` because it includes `$data_type5` `Species_Name`.

Same with "below" dataframes, i.e. `$data_type1` with `Species_Name = Cerulean+` and `$data_type2` with `Species_Name = Cherry+` cannot have `$data_type5`, with `Species_Name = Cerulean+Cherry+`, `X.micron.` and `Y.micron.` matching values.

Or the rule may be that I would like to keep whichever `Species_Name` has higher number of "+" i.e. I want to keep Cerulean+Cherry+GFP+ over Cerulean+Cherry+ because the former has more "+".

Data frames are not ordered from longest name length to shortest.

Here is the data if you need it:

```
list(data_type1 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("Cerulean+", 
"Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", 
"Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", 
"Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", 
"Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", 
"Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", 
"Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", 
"Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", "Cerulean+", 
"Cerulean+", "Cerulean+"), X.micron. = c(903.59, 1136.7, 559.53, 
921.69, 1098.8, 435.11, 296.62, 89.74, 1013.8, 865.01, 879.5, 
835.4, 1035.1, 896.13, 377.66, 929.17, 1119.9, 608.22, 1133.6, 
1092.1, 1038.5, 193.61, 400.89, 1066.3, 861.57, 794.03, 680.6, 
270.37, 113.76, 875.61, 791.82, 111.57, 1146.1, 672.51, 267.26, 
814.24, 1013.3, 722.9), Y.micron. = c(715, 795.88, 759.29, 35.87, 
530.01, 905.22, 363.17, 773.4, 716.84, 746.88, 768.9, 540.12, 
140.22, 839.33, 845.79, 758.91, 1025.8, 604.25, 806.34, 1154.4, 
133.05, 1018.3, 1137.2, 1001.6, 693.72, 779.68, 756.84, 944.59, 
588.05, 792.84, 720.28, 580.06, 1038.8, 763.88, 195.9, 663.11, 
1086.7, 786.59), Type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L)), data_type2 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", "Cherry+", 
"Cherry+", "Cherry+"), X.micron. = c(490.07, 766.81, 797.73, 
842.87, 58.05, 568.52, 846.38, 797.08, 768.6, 171.05, 844.6, 
827.65, 437.42, 346.92, 291.71, 1053, 351.06, 501.02, 142.71, 
754.16, 710.78, 663.39, 21.4, 847.78, 1014.6, 377.66, 503.92, 
263.6, 81.35, 967.7, 985.96, 875.03, 750.01, 707.24, 599.88, 
993.13, 321.22, 623.19, 1048.5, 843.97, 893, 270.37, 774.72, 
753.17, 288.03, 859.16, 295.73, 77.45, 654.81, 3.278, 91.48, 
1145.5, 726.58, 57.82, 912.42, 221.13, 600.84, 1021.4, 382.66, 
322.72, 150.84, 1046.1, 151.5, 98.83, 478.18, 617.61, 616.06, 
831.46, 626.67), Y.micron. = c(360.15, 696.3, 787.09, 1096.4, 
786.82, 802.73, 619.48, 1079.3, 561.24, 682.11, 1086.9, 466.11, 
13.01, 839.55, 600.19, 548.48, 809.79, 37.7, 697.62, 179.86, 
384.97, 750.37, 342.3, 557.81, 1125.4, 845.79, 45.17, 815.17, 
745.71, 1142.3, 1114, 625.81, 599.2, 1040.5, 628.34, 720.89, 
740.14, 44.63, 1136.6, 590.3, 1112.3, 944.59, 976.35, 173.17, 
647.45, 567.98, 640.85, 664.03, 703.04, 329.8, 621.6, 1080.7, 
638.07, 605.3, 1144.5, 997.47, 775.7, 1130.9, 852.37, 748.63, 
698.32, 1154.7, 656.57, 704.17, 949.61, 1016.2, 41.08, 761.83, 
1013.8), Type = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-69L)), data_type3 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", "GFP+", 
"GFP+", "GFP+"), X.micron. = c(60.85, 187.03, 405.63, 995.68, 
788.17, 403.23, 507.68, 559.53, 172.36, 921.69, 673.6, 861.81, 
256.96, 1098.8, 435.11, 568.52, 89.74, 43.48, 873.96, 797.08, 
1013.8, 879.5, 628.57, 624.58, 1035.1, 167.98, 519.78, 453.7, 
230.96, 181.64, 896.13, 236.27, 744.66, 74.49, 351.06, 491.68, 
142.71, 696.65, 1076.8, 497.16, 663.39, 862.54, 377.66, 675.65, 
496.54, 929.17, 1119.9, 430.33, 608.22, 499.72, 875.5, 723.47, 
243.17, 263.6, 1015.2, 429.89, 400.99, 152.42, 1038.5, 193.61, 
717.22, 551.1, 81.35, 985.96, 400.89, 820.52, 763.65, 967.91, 
87.53, 546.95, 1052.9, 505.81, 1066.3, 847.51, 1021, 861.57, 
915.99, 1113.4, 606.47, 877.1, 527.31, 647.58, 1048.5, 955.56, 
893, 537.71, 680.6, 862.57, 657.29, 430.07, 270.37, 113.76, 339.26, 
222.95, 891.63, 763.12, 621.69, 283.9, 89.75, 145.37, 752.16, 
874.04, 68.4, 284.71, 593.8, 323.06, 660.01, 871.7, 541.15, 278.56, 
517.04, 929.6, 880.31, 582.68, 192.82, 681.3, 618.3, 523.79, 
286.45, 61.58, 871.06, 223.01, 820.95, 524.11, 360.94, 242.29, 
587.52, 821.13, 881.42, 267.26, 896.3, 912.42, 409.57, 555.53, 
171.12, 914.89, 1025.9, 690.5, 990.02, 503.58, 190.39, 1139.8, 
382.66, 451.53, 574.32, 868.03, 378.36, 935.32, 94.81, 887.37, 
658.33, 1046.1, 787.93, 824.66, 908.15, 151.5, 316.87, 507.09, 
98.83, 282.62, 35.12, 722.9, 380.33, 483.43, 1002.8, 805.7, 367.65, 
707.84, 782.66, 743.08, 671.51, 600.27, 536.82, 312.41, 785.1, 
214.96, 759.26, 436.96, 329.87), Y.micron. = c(45.17, 699.99, 
864.51, 1153, 1085.9, 758.15, 909.63, 759.29, 517.66, 35.87, 
44.52, 527.6, 839.18, 530.01, 905.22, 802.73, 773.4, 588.78, 
1128.9, 1079.3, 716.84, 768.9, 779.9, 833.44, 140.22, 691.01, 
1035.9, 111.18, 663.99, 519.47, 839.33, 833.99, 982.81, 775.99, 
809.79, 1038.8, 697.62, 399.51, 732.28, 1046, 750.37, 1109.2, 
845.79, 262.32, 260.58, 758.91, 1025.8, 730.98, 604.25, 269.39, 
1151.9, 760.46, 651.32, 815.17, 646.41, 846.82, 857.22, 1035, 
133.05, 1018.3, 748.67, 849.22, 745.71, 1114, 1137.2, 1066.1, 
1079.6, 1112.6, 590.92, 84.27, 491.77, 788.93, 1001.6, 1024.6, 
720.32, 693.72, 671.41, 1041.2, 3.049, 1138.6, 241.3, 152.2, 
1136.6, 609.36, 1112.3, 1070.3, 756.84, 738.7, 774.74, 777.23, 
944.59, 588.05, 1012.2, 893.77, 644.27, 1067.7, 143.06, 1054.3, 
712.31, 1032.3, 1079.6, 662.26, 607.11, 1025.4, 123.8, 889.3, 
147.82, 530.42, 239.63, 1022.3, 788.9, 809.82, 717.54, 63.88, 
707.28, 41.92, 211.76, 1041, 1015.4, 572.29, 765.91, 711.32, 
1098, 787.61, 862.34, 958.59, 763.37, 721.18, 686.84, 195.9, 
808.81, 1144.5, 561.97, 856.44, 507.22, 732, 789.94, 403.6, 1159.1, 
707.02, 583, 688.03, 852.37, 30, 93.07, 686.16, 727.53, 558.68, 
659.24, 741.47, 1097.4, 1154.7, 1110, 716.84, 1141, 656.57, 894.29, 
932.13, 704.17, 714.7, 781.38, 786.59, 706.07, 796.56, 1050.3, 
1070.3, 106.65, 369.91, 726.79, 738.74, 253.97, 826.5, 1034.7, 
731.69, 1121.7, 495.06, 1071.6, 1067.9, 888.47), Type = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -179L)), data_type4 = structure(list(
    Species_Name = c("TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", 
    "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+", "TFP+"), X.micron. = c(457.37, 797.73, 
    559.53, 921.69, 464.24, 256.96, 435.11, 568.52, 89.74, 457.94, 
    1035.1, 286.79, 511.92, 529.14, 298.42, 999.6, 896.13, 744.66, 
    351.06, 696.65, 514, 929.17, 1119.9, 608.22, 1080.6, 592.14, 
    1038.5, 193.61, 590.53, 400.89, 820.52, 861.57, 794.03, 1048.5, 
    955.56, 822.18, 680.6, 862.57, 270.37, 809.16, 447.29, 891.63, 
    89.75, 457.03, 681.3, 816.16, 672.51, 506.63, 961.07, 267.26, 
    613.44, 129.37, 278.87, 828.25, 382.66, 127.09, 391.42, 935.32, 
    620.63, 646.99, 787.93, 627.24, 109.97, 98.83, 525.19, 93.64, 
    1013.3, 652.08, 1018.1, 782.66, 785.1, 956.45, 634.32), Y.micron. = c(259.31, 
    787.09, 759.29, 35.87, 27.28, 839.18, 905.22, 802.73, 773.4, 
    250.48, 140.22, 670.66, 224.43, 697.39, 514.61, 1097.9, 839.33, 
    982.81, 809.79, 399.51, 214.91, 758.91, 1025.8, 604.25, 1013.9, 
    8.792, 133.05, 1018.3, 985.91, 1137.2, 1066.1, 693.72, 779.68, 
    1136.6, 609.36, 824.79, 756.84, 738.7, 944.59, 383.2, 248.24, 
    644.27, 712.31, 238.57, 41.92, 804.53, 763.88, 242.94, 465.35, 
    195.9, 821.53, 939.59, 674.39, 1060.9, 852.37, 578.39, 609.06, 
    558.68, 814.94, 116.11, 1110, 110.35, 964.4, 704.17, 705.82, 
    762.21, 1086.7, 104.16, 1092.1, 726.79, 1121.7, 470.81, 105.34
    ), Type = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -73L)), data_type5 = structure(list(
    Species_Name = c("Cerulean+Cherry+", "Cerulean+Cherry+"), 
    X.micron. = c(270.37, 377.66), Y.micron. = c(944.59, 845.79
    ), Type = c(5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)), data_type6 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("Cerulean+GFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+"), X.micron. = c(1013.8, 1035.1, 
1038.5, 1066.3, 1098.8, 1119.9, 113.76, 193.61, 267.26, 270.37, 
377.66, 400.89, 435.11, 559.53, 608.22, 680.6, 722.9, 861.57, 
879.5, 89.74, 896.13, 921.69, 929.17), Y.micron. = c(716.84, 
140.22, 133.05, 1001.6, 530.01, 1025.8, 588.05, 1018.3, 195.9, 
944.59, 845.79, 1137.2, 905.22, 759.29, 604.25, 756.84, 786.59, 
693.72, 768.9, 773.4, 839.33, 35.87, 758.91), Type = c(6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L)), data_type7 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("Cerulean+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+TFP+", "Cerulean+TFP+"), X.micron. = c(1013.3, 1035.1, 
1038.5, 1119.9, 193.61, 267.26, 270.37, 400.89, 435.11, 559.53, 
608.22, 672.51, 680.6, 794.03, 861.57, 89.74, 896.13, 921.69, 
929.17), Y.micron. = c(1086.7, 140.22, 133.05, 1025.8, 1018.3, 
195.9, 944.59, 1137.2, 905.22, 759.29, 604.25, 763.88, 756.84, 
779.68, 693.72, 773.4, 839.33, 35.87, 758.91), Type = c(7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L)), data_type8 = structure(list(
    Species_Name = c("Cerulean+Cherry+GFP+", "Cerulean+Cherry+GFP+"
    ), X.micron. = c(270.37, 377.66), Y.micron. = c(944.59, 845.79
    ), Type = c(8L, 8L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)), data_type9 = structure(list(Species_Name = "Cerulean+Cherry+TFP+", 
    X.micron. = 270.37, Y.micron. = 944.59, Type = 9L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), data_type10 = structure(list(Species_Name = "Cerulean+Cherry+GFP+TFP+", 
    X.micron. = 270.37, Y.micron. = 944.59, Type = 10L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)), data_type11 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", 
"Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+", "Cerulean+GFP+TFP+"
), X.micron. = c(1035.1, 1038.5, 1119.9, 193.61, 267.26, 270.37, 
400.89, 435.11, 559.53, 608.22, 680.6, 861.57, 89.74, 896.13, 
921.69, 929.17), Y.micron. = c(140.22, 133.05, 1025.8, 1018.3, 
195.9, 944.59, 1137.2, 905.22, 759.29, 604.25, 756.84, 693.72, 
773.4, 839.33, 35.87, 758.91), Type = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L)), data_type12 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("Cherry+GFP+", 
"Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", 
"Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", 
"Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", "Cherry+GFP+", 
"Cherry+GFP+"), X.micron. = c(1046.1, 1048.5, 142.71, 151.5, 
263.6, 270.37, 351.06, 377.66, 382.66, 568.52, 663.39, 797.08, 
81.35, 893, 912.42, 98.83, 985.96), Y.micron. = c(1154.7, 1136.6, 
697.62, 656.57, 815.17, 944.59, 809.79, 845.79, 852.37, 802.73, 
750.37, 1079.3, 745.71, 1112.3, 1144.5, 704.17, 1114), Type = c(12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L
)), data_type13 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("Cherry+TFP+", 
"Cherry+TFP+", "Cherry+TFP+", "Cherry+TFP+", "Cherry+TFP+", "Cherry+TFP+", 
"Cherry+TFP+"), X.micron. = c(1048.5, 270.37, 351.06, 382.66, 
568.52, 797.73, 98.83), Y.micron. = c(1136.6, 944.59, 809.79, 
852.37, 802.73, 787.09, 704.17), Type = c(13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
13L, 13L, 13L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L)), 
    data_type14 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("Cherry+GFP+TFP+", 
    "Cherry+GFP+TFP+", "Cherry+GFP+TFP+", "Cherry+GFP+TFP+", 
    "Cherry+GFP+TFP+", "Cherry+GFP+TFP+"), X.micron. = c(1048.5, 
    270.37, 351.06, 382.66, 568.52, 98.83), Y.micron. = c(1136.6, 
    944.59, 809.79, 852.37, 802.73, 704.17), Type = c(14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -6L)), data_type15 = structure(list(Species_Name = c("GFP+TFP+", 
    "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", 
    "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", 
    "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", 
    "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", 
    "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", 
    "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", 
    "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+", "GFP+TFP+"), X.micron. = c(1035.1, 
    1038.5, 1048.5, 1119.9, 193.61, 256.96, 267.26, 270.37, 351.06, 
    382.66, 400.89, 435.11, 559.53, 568.52, 608.22, 680.6, 681.3, 
    696.65, 744.66, 782.66, 785.1, 787.93, 820.52, 861.57, 862.57, 
    89.74, 89.75, 891.63, 896.13, 921.69, 929.17, 935.32, 955.56, 
    98.83), Y.micron. = c(140.22, 133.05, 1136.6, 1025.8, 1018.3, 
    839.18, 195.9, 944.59, 809.79, 852.37, 1137.2, 905.22, 759.29, 
    802.73, 604.25, 756.84, 41.92, 399.51, 982.81, 726.79, 1121.7, 
    1110, 1066.1, 693.72, 738.7, 773.4, 712.31, 644.27, 839.33, 
    35.87, 758.91, 558.68, 609.36, 704.17), Type = c(15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
    15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -34L)))
```

Comment: It's not clear to me why `Cerulean+Cherry+` can be in `$data_type8` but not in `$data_type5`. What's the logic that excludes the other way around?

Comment: @akrun, the condition is that if the X.micron. and Y.micron. values of a data frame with Species_Name that are already in another dataframe, they can only be in one data frame, and It has to be the one with the highest number of names. So, for example, values in dataframe with Species_Name = Cerulean+Cherry+ cannot be in data frame with only Species_Name = Cerulean+ (or Species_Name = Cherry+)

Comment: @Phil because of the way I've programmed my code: At the beginning I had a list of data frames with the info of 4 Species_Name (the shortest ones) and I had to match the X.microns. and Y.microns. values between each species so that I could see if two or more species coincided in the same X and Y position and create a new Species_Name combining the names of the original ones. But now I need to delete the original species information that matched by having made these combinations.

Comment: @Phil I could edit the question and share that part of the code, I've tried to do this in that part but my programming skills are limited and the data I've shared is the output as far as I've been able to get

Comment: @AlejandroRivera so is the rule that you want to keep whichever species name is longest? i.e. you want to keep `Cerulean+Cherry+GFP+`  over `Cerulean+Cherry+` because the former has more characters?

Comment: @Phil yes, or as you see all names have a "+" at the end, it would be better to keep those with a higher number of "+", that way the length of the names don't influence in case we have longer names.

Comment: @akrun data.frame output or list of data.frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is after assigning the list into an object called `my_list`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

my_list_filt <- my_list |> 
  bind_rows() |>
  as_tibble() |> 
  arrange(desc(str_length(Species_Name))) |> 
  mutate(row_id = row_number(),
         Species_split = str_split(Species_Name, "\\+")) |> 
  tidyr::unnest(Species_split) |> 
  distinct(X.micron., Y.micron., Species_split, .keep_all = TRUE) |> 
  distinct(row_id, .keep_all = TRUE) |> 
  select(-row_id, -Species_split) |> 
  arrange(Type) |> 
  group_split(Type)

 names(my_list_filt) <- purrr::map_chr(my_list_filt, 
                                       function(x) paste0("data_type", unique(x[["Type"]])))
```

Comment: It works perfectly, just one thing: could it be possible to separate each Type/Species_Name in diffrent data frames or list of data framaes as in the data I've shared?

Comment: Revised to provide a list of data frames instead.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps - bind the list elements to a single dataset with additional column from the names of the list ('data_type'), then order the rows (`arrange`) in descending based on the count of the number of `+` in 'Species_Name', 'data_type', get the unique rows with `distinct` on 'X.micron.'m 'Y.micron.', and `split` to a `list` of data.frames

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) # version 1.0.1
library(stringr)
out <- list_rbind(lst1, names_to = 'data_type') %>% 
  arrange(desc(str_count(Species_Name, fixed("+"))), data_type) %>% 
  distinct(X.micron., Y.micron., .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(data_type = factor(data_type,
     levels = gtools::mixedsort(unique(data_type)))) %>%
  {split(.[-1], .$data_type)}
```

-output

```
> sum(sapply(out, nrow))
[1] 281
> head(out)
$data_type1
   Species_Name X.micron. Y.micron. Type
56    Cerulean+    903.59    715.00    1
57    Cerulean+   1136.70    795.88    1
58    Cerulean+    296.62    363.17    1
59    Cerulean+    865.01    746.88    1
60    Cerulean+    835.40    540.12    1
61    Cerulean+   1133.60    806.34    1
62    Cerulean+   1092.10   1154.40    1
63    Cerulean+    875.61    792.84    1
64    Cerulean+    791.82    720.28    1
65    Cerulean+    111.57    580.06    1
66    Cerulean+   1146.10   1038.80    1
67    Cerulean+    814.24    663.11    1

$data_type2
    Species_Name X.micron. Y.micron. Type
68       Cherry+   490.070    360.15    2
69       Cherry+   766.810    696.30    2
70       Cherry+   842.870   1096.40    2
71       Cherry+    58.050    786.82    2
72       Cherry+   846.380    619.48    2
73       Cherry+   768.600    561.24    2
74       Cherry+   171.050    682.11    2
75       Cherry+   844.600   1086.90    2
76       Cherry+   827.650    466.11    2
77       Cherry+   437.420     13.01    2
78       Cherry+   346.920    839.55    2
79       Cherry+   291.710    600.19    2
80       Cherry+  1053.000    548.48    2
81       Cherry+   501.020     37.70    2
82       Cherry+   754.160    179.86    2
83       Cherry+   710.780    384.97    2
84       Cherry+    21.400    342.30    2
85       Cherry+   847.780    557.81    2
....
```

Comment: What version of purrr or RStudio are you using? Because I have a miss function error in "list_rbind()"